# What does "Créeme que si vas a Colombia no te vas a querer ir" mean?

Tags: significado, colombia, verbo-pronominal

I got this message in a chat from a Spanish speaking guy:

> Créeme que si vas a Colombia no te vas a querer ir.

What is the meaning here?

- you don't want to leave
- you don't want to go to Colombia

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It means "you won't want to leave".

This is an example of a radical change in meaning when a verb (in this case *ir*) becomes pronominal. A pronominal verb is always accompanied by an object pronoun. It looks like a reflexive verb but it isn't.

You have *ir* three times in your sentence, but the second one (the second *vas*) is just part of the [periphrastic future](http://www.leaflanguages.org/spanish-grammar-the-periphrastic-future-ira/) (*vas a hacer algo* = "you're going to do something") so let's leave that one out.

> *Créeme que si **vas** a Colombia no te vas a querer **ir**.*

The first ***vas*** is the verb in its bare form, where it means "to go" in general. When found alone without a complement (such as *a Colombia*) we tend to parse it as "to go there, somewhere", that is, going to or towards some place.

The infinitive ***ir*** is the pronominal form; believe it or not the pronoun is *te*. This is sort of a complicated example because you have *ir* subordinated to *querer* and *querer* in turn forming part of the periphrastic construction, but bear with me here. You could rephrase this as

> *Créeme que si **vas** a Colombia no vas a querer **irte**.*

The thing is (finally coming to the point), pronominal *ir* doesn't mean "to go" in general, but "to leave, to go away". That's why the sentence makes sense.

The pronoun is *te* because we're referring to the second person singular. If this were in the first person singular you would say

> *Si voy a Colombia no me voy a querer ir.*

And in the third person singular:

> *Si va a Colombia no se va a querer ir.*

The third person reflexive pronoun *se* is the one that is customarily used to cite the pronominal verbs in textbooks. In this case we would say the verb is *irse*. Dictionaries, however, might cite these simply with the bare infinitive and note that they are pronominal. The DLE, for example, conflates the two main meanings of *[ir](http://dle.rae.es/?id=M5ucdgy)* in its first entry for it, adding "U. t. c. prnl.", which means *Úsase también como pronominal*, "Also used as pronominal".

Answer (score 2):

> "No vas a..."

or its affirmative:

> "Vas a ..."

is a very usual verb phrase to indicate a foreseeable behavior or reaction attributable to your interlocutor. To translate it, I'd use "won't" (or "will" in the affirmative) to express certainty:

- If you ever go to Colombia, believe me you **won't feel like leaving.** (Créeme que si vas a Colombia no te vas a querer ir.)
- If you ever go to Colombia, believe me you **will feel like staying.** (Créeme que si vas a Colombia te vas a querer quedar.)